# Check if Stylecop warnings have been reduced

Tags: merge, build, azure-devops, stylecop

I am using Azure DevOps, and I want to add a policy to my dev branch which ensures that the number of StyleCop warnings will be reduced after merge.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

**Note:**

I cannot remove all warnings at once, so I cannot have check which tells if there are zero warnings or not.

I know one answer is to write a scrip which builds on server and passes or fails depending on the reduction, but I am more interested in a way which allows to add a policy right on Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check if Stylecop warnings have been reduced

As we know, there is no such out of branch policy to detect whether the number of StyleCop warnings has reduced.

That because the branch policy could not get the number of StyleCop warnings directly. We have to manually develop a script to compare the number of StyleCop warnings on the two branches to be merged.

To achieve this, we could add a [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) in branch policy, then add a build pipeline to compare the number of StyleCop warnings on the two branches to be merged. If the number of StyleCop warnings does not decrease, then we set the result of the pipeline added in Build Validation to fail.